# c#: Adding value to label

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, label

How when I click my datagridview command is run?

```
          Int64 sum = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dg_Cheque.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells["True_False"].Value) == true) //Cells[0] Because in cell 0th cell we have added checkbox
            {
                sum +=Convert.ToInt64(dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

In any event I write it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please

Comment: dont forget to update the UpdatePanel also after the Click Event.

Comment: Don't really know what your after but you can remove '== true' in the foreach loop, it isn't needed

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you click on the DataGridView.  If you want to run this command when you double click a cell within the grid you could use the `CellContentDoubleClick` event.

The full list of events for a [DataGridView can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx)

**EDIT:**

It appears that you want to capture a click event for a CheckBox within the DataGrid?

In order to capture the Checkbox changed event you can subscribe to the `OnCellValueChanged` event.  Within the EventArgs check to see what column has been changed.  If it is your checkbox column then you can run you command.

Something along these lines of this (untested):

```
private void DataGridView1_OnCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

   if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1) // Replace 0 with the checkbox col index
   {
         if ((bool)this.DataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == true)
         {
             // Checkbox is checked so call you command
         }
   }

}
```

Comment: This event was not the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) event

Comment: This event was not the answer

Answer (score 0):

All events do not respond

This column is a checkedbox

I must click twice to give the answer that first click